# Which statisical test to use when comparing a subgroup to a total group?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, group-differences

Currently I am evaluation my the results of my research.
Now I am trying to find a statistical test to test the significance between two groups. However I can't seem to find what how to achieve this.

I have 126 patients without cancer and 30 patients with a certain form of cancer. In percentage out of all admitted patients (897) this is 20,2% without cancer and 19,0% (30 out of 274 total with a certain disease) with cancer.

Now I would like to compare the total study healthy population to the ill population and whether this difference is sigficant.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have the data of information from health people? If not, you cannot do anything.

Comment: Best to compare those in the group to those outside the group. When comparing those in the group to everyone, you're inevitably comparing those in the group with themselves. // From your description it's difficult to determine what the group of interest is--much less relevant counts. What role does the 'certain disease' play in this. What subgroups are distinguishable among 'admitted patients'? Admitted to what and according to what criteria?

Comment: Dear BruceET, Thank you for the response. You are right, I decided to define the groups as patients without cancer (650) and with cancer (250). Now I would like to test for significance between the admitted department of the hospital. So for example 120 patients were admitted to the department of pulmonary medicine, of these 120 patient 80 didn't have cancer while 40 did suffer from cancer. How can I test whether this difference is significant?